# How to check whether an event has guest list or not before saving?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I have two tables "Event" and "GuestList". While saving an event we can mention whether it is a public or private event. If it is a private event we must have a guestlist if it is not it is optional to have a guest list.

Now

```
 1. how to check before saving the event whether the guest list is empty or not.? 
 2. how to relate those two tables.
```

I am using django framework and postgresql database.

```
  class Event(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserInfo, null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    event_type = models.BooleanField(default=False)     #public or private 
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  class GuestList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserInfo, null=False)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, null=False)
    g_email = models.EmailField(null=False, blank=True, unique=True,
          validators=[validators.validate_email])
    g_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    attendence = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=ATTENDENCE_STATUS, null=False)
```

For an event the user should invite some guests how to see whether a private event has a guest list or not?

Comment: Can you show the view/model's save method that you have currently ?

Comment: Are you using a form? in the admin? Can you post some code?

Comment: not using any forms, we will get json data and we need to store that.

Comment: You won't be able to ensure that a guest list is present when saving an event, as you can't create a GuestList instance before the Event object is saved.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way foreign keys work (requiring a primary key on the related table before they can be saved, therefore having to save the related object first), you can't create (and save) a `GuestList` object before you create (and save) an `Event` object.

You could, however, write a custom manager object to handle this logic for you, and always use that. Something like this (untested code):

```
class EventManager(models.Manager):
    def create_event(guest_list=None, **kwargs):
        guest_list = guest_list or []
        private = kwargs.get('event_type', False)
        if private and not guest_list:
            raise ValidationError('Cannot create a private event without a guest list')
        event = self.create(**kwargs)
        for guest in guest_list:
            guest.event = event
            guest.save()
        return event

class Event(models.Manager):
    objects = EventManager()
    # rest of you models...
```

This is how I would use such a manager:

In the view that allows people to add a guest to an existing event, do it like you normally would:

```
guest_list = GuestList(
    g_email = 'new.person@email.com',
    g_name = 'New Person',
    user = my_user,
    attendance = 'yes',
    event = the_event_to_add_to,
)
guest_list.save()
```

And for adding a brand new event (or adding a guest list to an event that doesn't exist yet, same thing):

```
guest_list = None

if event_type == True: # private! Build up a guest list however you like
    guest_list = [
        GuestList(g_email='bob@bob.com', g_name='Bob', user=my_user, attendance='yes'),
        GuestList(g_email='dan@dan.com', g_name='Dan', user=my_user, attendance='yes'),
        GuestList(g_email='terry@terry.com', g_name='Terry', user=my_user, attendance='yes'),
    ]

event = Event.objects.create_event(
    user = my_user,
    title = 'My Awesome Event',
    description = 'This is going to be great',
    guest_list = guest_list,
    event_type = event_type
)
event.save()
```

Comment: Hi @Ben thanks for the answer but a small clarification, I have to add guest for an event which is existed when a separate url for adding guest is called., and for creating an event separate url will be called.But neither I can add guest to the non-existing event nor I can create a private event without adding guest to the event.can u help me on this?

Comment: I've tried to add more detail onto how I'd use the manager to achieve what you want - otherwise, I'm a bit confused by what you're asking :) I hope it helps?

Answer (score 0):

@user2936254, As per my understanding your problem is -

- Event is created on a separate URL of a website
- Guest List is added on a separate URL of website

So without guest list you can not create a private event, and if event is not created then how will you add guest list.

I can propose 2 solutions for this problem -

1. Change the flow of your website.

   - Either create event and add guest list on same URL
   - Or when event is added then put event details in session and once guest list is added create actual event in database along with guest list
2. Change your database

   - Remove event from GuestList table.
   - create a mapping table of Event and GuestList, which will only have eventid and guestlistid's of all guest. that means one to many relationship between event and guestlist.
   - Now you can save the Guestlist first and then create an Event.

I hope i understood your problem correctly